# Function doesn't work when the new html appears

Tags: jquery

I have this function `$(function() {
        $("body").jqTransform();
    });` in my `functions.js` file.

It is a plugin and I use to style my inputs. It works perfectly. However, when the new inputs come through ajax, it doesn't work for them and usual simple inputs are being shown.

What should do I do?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try putting `$("body").jqTransform()` in the Ajax callback.

Answer (score 0):

Call `jqTransform()` again in your ajax callback function - after the new HTML is inserted (either the same way you do it with `body`, or just on the container that has the new inputs - preferred).

Answer (score 0):

$() < whatever is passed through it will only be called once the document is loaded. An obvious way to do is to call it again after the Ajax request.